# Defaultgateway do not detect MAC-addresses

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dhcp, mac-address

Today I was experimenting a bit with the user interface of my cisco router that is the default gateway of my LAN-network. I have two computers and a couple of smartphones atached to it trought WIFI 802.11. Unexperienced - I somehow clicked **remove all** in the wireless-tab. Then I lost all my connections. I thought - well DHCP should fix this, right? NOPE, a small hell started, really frustrated. What was the problem here? I thought the router is broadcasting information to the hosts and the host responds with its MAC-address. Then the router can lease private ip-addresses.

What I had to do - was to attach an ethernet-cable between one of the computers and the router - then in this wireless config I manually entered the computers MAC-addresses. After that - there was no problem for the router to realese IP-addresses and consequently connect wireless to internet.

SO my question - why could the router not automatically get the hosts MAC-addresses? This was no problem before so I cannot understand what happend in the cofiguration when I hassardly disabled the WLAN.

Would be extremely greatfull if someone could explain this?

Answer (score 1):

Security.  I don't know what other settings have been made in your router, but there are configurations that prevent unknown devices from connecting.

Comment: thanks, yes you are probably right. something about the wpa-key?

Comment: doubtful... In my netgear router the options are called "Turn on Access Control" and then setting "block all new devices".  I don't know what it would be called in your cisco router.